# Download Checked Files in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, file, checkbox

I'm creating a web page which has DataList. All Items in DataList have Checkboxes front of them. User checks some files, or all files, maybe just one file to download them. How can i make it happen? I'm using ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms. Thanks :)

Comment: have you tried something? some code?

Comment: Not yet, I don't have any idea about how to do it. :(

Comment: Break your question down. First of all you need to research into how you handle the checking of a check box. A point in the right direction would be to look at the checked changed server side event. Or do you want to do this when they click a button? In which case you need to iterate through your controls to check which checkboxes are checked in order to invoke the download of the corresponding files.

Comment: Loop over all items. Find which items are checked. If more that one item is to be downloaded, add them to a zip file. Write contents to be downloaded to response. Done.

Answer (score 2):

there are two ways doing it

1). Open multiple window with javascript with new name, call your aspx page in that new window.

2).First zip all selected files and then download that single zip file